# double encoding through cp1252 and base 64

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

From a client I am getting a pdf file, which is encoded in cp 1252 and for transfer is also encoded in base 64. Till now a shell program returns the file into the original form through this code line:
output= [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String(input))
and this works.

Now I am implementing a python version, to supersede this implementation. This looks generally like this:

```
enc_file = read_from_txt.open_file(location_of_file)
plain_file= base64.b64decode(enc_file)
with open('filename', 'w') as writer:
    writer.write(plain_file.decode('cp1252'))
```

where read_from_txt.open_file just does this:

```
with open(file_location, 'rb') as fileReader:
    read = fileReader.read()
    return read
```

But for some reason, I am getting an error in the plain_file.decode('cp1252'), where it can not decode a line in the file. From what I am understanding though, the python program should do exactly the same, as the powershell does.

Concrete error is:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 188: character maps to undefined

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"a pdf file, which is encoded in cp 1252 and for transfer is also encoded in base 64."* - PDF is a binary file format, what does "encoded in cp1252" even mean there?

Comment: From what I understood from the Powershell Script, which was given to me and is shown, the PDF File in cp1252 (for whatever reason) and for transfer additionally encoded into base 64. The power shell code works though, I could try it. The main question I have is, why the python code does not do the same thing.

Comment: That's like saying *"I have a JPG file (or an EXE file) that's encoded in cp1252..."* - it doesn't make sense. cp1252 turns a string into bytes. PDF (or JPG, or EXE) already is bytes. Base64 turns bytes into string, that part makes sense. I would suggest base64-decoding your incoming data, and writing the result directly to a file opened in `'wb'` mode.

Comment: You solved it. I know it didnt make any sense. My task was just to reimplement the powershell script. And that I did. Without questioning why they did or why it worked. Works actually though when im just decoding in base 64 and the writing to file directly. Thanks a lot. Sorry for the trouble and the stupidnes  of the question though

Comment: That's all good, no need to apologize. You learned something, that's the whole point. :)